How to reuse layout.component.ts with routing in Angular?
my goal is to reuse accounts.layout.ts for 2 paths /v3/signin/identifier and /v3/signin/challenge/pwd.
The problem is <ng-content select="[right-content-action]" /> do not work well with <router-outlet/>
What I've tried:

create a accounts.layout.ts

It works well if I use it in sign-in-identifier.page.html.
accounts.layout.ts 
<div class="overlay" [class.overlay-show]="showOverlay"></div>

<div class="main">
  <img class="logo" src="/assets/google-logo.svg" alt="google logo" />
  <div class="section">
    <div class="left-content">
      <span class="com-headline-5">{{ title }}</span>
      <span class="com-headline-6">{{ description }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="right-content">
      <ng-content select="[right-content-input]" />

      <div class="actions">
        <ng-content select="[right-content-action]" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


sign-in-identifier.page.html
<acc-accounts
  title="Sign In"
  description="Use your Google Account"
  [showOverlay]="isLoading"
>
  <com-input-text
    #inputEmail
    placeholder="Email"
    [(value)]="email"
    [errorMessage]="errorMessage"
    right-content-input
  />

  @if (isCreateAccountEnabled) {
    <com-button-basic (buttonClick)="onCreateAccount()" right-content-action
      >Create account</com-button-basic
    >
  }

  <com-button-flat
    (buttonClick)="onNext()"
    [disabled]="isLoading"
    right-content-action
    >Next</com-button-flat
  >
</acc-accounts>


try to use it with <router-outlet /> in app.component.html

app.component.html
<acc-accounts>
  <router-outlet />
</acc-accounts>

Expected result:

Actual result:


You're not rendering the <ng-content></ng-content> in your accounts.layout.ts. Only the left and right attributes. So your <router-outlet> will never show up

@Pieterjan thank you for pointing that out. After adding <router-outlet />, it works. The problem now is that <router-outlet /> creates a hidden <router-outlet /> and also <acc-sign-in-identifier> tag which wraps the <com-button-basic> and <com-button-flat> which cause the layout to be weird. For now, I will import AccountsLayout in each Page. I checked the network tab, it do not download AccountsLayout when I switch to another path. Documentation in GitHub repository

You have to create a wrapper component, where you explicitly specify the ng-content because when you run it through router-outlet the selector query will not work!
So your app.component.html
<router-outlet />

All the routes rendered in the router-outlet will have the acc-accounts wrapped around it!
<acc-accounts>
  <!-- your component contents inside here -->
</acc-accounts>


Hi, if I add <router-outlet/> to the AccountsLayout, the layout is becoming weird because it wraps the contents of sign-in-identifier with <acc-sign-in-identifier> ... here is the <com-button-basic> and <com-button-flat> </acc-sign-in-identifier. Also, how do you pass the title, description, and showOverlay and prevent <router-outlet> from wrapping the <com-button-basic> and <com-button-flat>?

This is the repository, in case you need to experiment. GitHub repository
